# Dropdown menu with only CSS

Tags: html, css

Goodmorning :D

I am trying to make a menu for my website. In my CSS I have a `.responsive-menu` `ul`
I want that to show when the screen width is 750px. I made a `@media` for that but it is not working. I am trying to only use CSS so I dont want to use any javascript. When you have the website on fullscreen the menu is working like I want it the only problem is the responsive menu. I am using checkboxes to make the menu onclick.

So if the screen width is 750px than I want to `.menu` to go away and show the `.responsive-menu`

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="naam">
                <p>Bart van Bussel <i class="fa fa-check"></i></p>
            </div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="trigger" />
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"><span class="menu-naam">Menu</span></i></label>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li>
                                <a href="">Random stuff</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">stuff I made</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">About myself</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>About myself</li>
                    <li>stuff I made</li>
                    <li>Random stuff</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:arial;
}

/*--------Header-------*/

.header {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 16px -200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.naam p{
    font-size:25px;
    padding:12px;
    width:100%;
}

/*--------Menu-------*/

.menu ul li i {
    float:right;
    font-size:35px;
    position:relative;
    top:-65px;
    padding:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-53px;
}

.dropdown li a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:20px;
}

.menu-naam {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:8px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:3px;
}

.responsive-menu ul {
    display:none;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width:100%;
    top:50px;
}

.responsive-menu ul li {
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

#trigger {
    display: none;
}
#trigger:checked + .menu ul li ul {
    display: block;
}

#trigger:checked + .menu ul li {
    color:gray;
}

/*--------Media-------*/

@media screen and (max-width:750px) {
    .background p {
        font-size:900%;
    }
    .menu ul li ul li {
        display:none;
    }
    #trigger:checked + .responsive-menu ul {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me out with this :)

Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yj5hbc9r/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `#trigger:checked + .responsive-menu`, which doesn't work. The `+` operator only works on elements that are next to each other in the source.

Solution: use the `~` operator, which also works if there's stuff in between the two elements.

[New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/yj5hbc9r/2/).

Comment: Thank you :) was stuck on that for a few days!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:arial;
}

/*--------Header-------*/

.header {
    background-color:#f1f1f1;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 16px -200px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.naam p{
    font-size:25px;
    padding:12px;
    width:100%;
}

/*--------Menu-------*/

.menu ul li i {
    float:right;
    font-size:35px;
    position:relative;
    top:-65px;
    padding:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu ul li ul {
    display:none;
}

.menu ul li ul li {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    top:-53px;
}

.dropdown li a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:20px;
}

.menu-naam {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:25px;
    padding:8px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:3px;
}

.responsive-menu ul {
    display:none;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    width:100%;
    top:50px;
}

.responsive-menu ul li {
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

#trigger {
    display: none;
}
#trigger:checked + .menu ul li ul {
    display: block;
}

#trigger:checked + .menu ul li {
    color:gray;
}

/*--------Media-------*/

@media screen only and (max-width:750px) {
    .background p {
        font-size:900%;
    }
    .menu ul li ul li {
        display:none;
    }
    #trigger:checked + .responsive-menu ul {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/yj5hbc9r/1/)

Comment: No that is not working I want the .menu go go away and show the .responsive-menu when the screen is 750px width.

Comment: @IvinRaj It seems you were trying to solve a different problem that the OP described. If you were unsure what the OP wanted, you should have asked in a comment. See also [Can we care a little more about quality instead of quantity, please?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316112/1016716) on the meta, especially the comment that says, _The number of answers containing "try this" is twice as large as "use this"..._

Answer (score 0):

The @media It's working perfectly, the error is the selector that you used.

Where you say this, you only hidding **li**, not his parent **.menu**:

```
.menu ul li ul li {
    display:none;
}
```

and use a UL, you used display: none; on UL element, not the .responsive-menu

```
#trigger:checked + .responsive-menu ul{
    display: block;
}
```

Other thing: .responsive-menu are not nested to: #trigger:checked. The nested element to the #trigger is the .menu. So this wont work.

In resume, just do this inside your @media:

```
.menu{
    display:none;
}

.responsive-menu ul{
    display: block;
}
```

If my answer didn't help you, let me know, I explain better